# How to resize a picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, resize, resolution

I have a graphic for my company & I need it to be made larger so that the sign company can grow the image without loosing quality. How do I do that? I downloaded Alien Skin Software because I heard that the software would be able to help. I don't have Photoshop so I am looking for something easy. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Enlarging (and quality) **greatly** depends upon the nature of the original image. I would suggest you **ask the sign shop** what they would need to enlarge the image to a usable format. They are the professionals and will have more information than what you've provided here. Chances are, if it's just some png or jpg, you **can't** enlarge it and maintain the quality the sign shop would need.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have photoshop, then you can download gimp which is free desktop software but it is too bulky. 
But if you want to do direct on your browser then visit [www.photoeditoronlinefree.com](http://www.photoeditoronlinefree.com) and upload your image and select Editor, Then select free transform. 
this will highlight the border of the image to move the image size according to your need which will resize your image to your desired size to increase the quality.

If this seems hard, then just upload photo to that site and then make some small changes and try to save it which will asked to select quality of image which will increase pixel of image and in turns the picture will not blast while zooming. 
Hope it helps.